# Define function F which is big O but not big theta

Tags: asymptotics

Searching for one definition of $f :  \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

with $f' :  \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ defined with $f'(n) := f(n+1) - f(n)$

with the bounderies $f=O(f')$ and  $f \not= \ \theta(f')$

Definition:

$f=O(f') \Leftrightarrow \exists n_0 \in  \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq n_0 | f(n) \leq c_1 f'(n)  $ und
$f\not=\theta(f') \Leftrightarrow \not \exists n_0 \in  \mathbb{N} : \forall n 
\geq n_0 | c_2f'(n) \leq f(n) \leq c_3 f'(n)  $

I think i had to show that there is no $n_0$ the boundaries, but witg the $f'$ definition its not clear for me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Let $f(n)=n!$. Then $f'(n)=(n+1)!-n!=n\cdot n!$. So $f=O(f')$, but $f \not= \ \theta(f')$

Comment: WOW great!!Is there a way of getting this solution ? Or was i an the right track but did not think about such a solution

Comment: @Roby I had the following intuition. If $f$ grows slowly, then there is no essential difference between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$, so then $f’=O(f)$. So I considered a simple function $f$ which grows fast. It was $f(n)=n!$.

Comment: Hey, im sorry.. wanted to show that there is no $c_2$ for $\theta(f')$ with this  inequality $c_2 n \leq 1$ but that istn true ? :-/

Comment: @Roby For each $c_2>0$ there exists a number $n$ such that $c_2n>1$. In fact this is [axiom of Archimedes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property). :-)

Comment: you are right, thanks :)